# Java executable Jar as Service

Tags: install4j

I am new to install4j and exploring it for our product.

I build sample installer "Install a Service" screen. I can see service gets created. But I want to run my executable jar being managed by this service.

Please let me know how I can run Java executable on Service start using Install4j. I essentially want service should control the java code execution.
I saw "Run executable or Batch file" screen but this is not our requirement we want service to manage executable jar

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate a service on the "Launchers" step. In the class path configuration of your launcher, you specify your JAR file and for the main class you can then select the main class from your JAR file.

Then you can select that executable in the "Install a service" action.